# How to change text in EditText at runtime in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change text of edit text at runtime,like i type character in edittext and if edittext lenth is greater then 3 then it should maintain bracket.

If anyone done this Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Trapti

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by "maintain bracket"?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for the EditText that is called whenever characters are entered or removed from the EditText field:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_field_id);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          // This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters 
          // beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after.  
        }

        @Override 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          // This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters 
          // beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before.
        }

        @Override 
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          // This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has 
          // been changed.
        }
      });
```

See the documentation for [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for further details.